# How to hide HTML5 web player throbber (buffering animation)?

Tags: css, html, video, throbber

Is there a way to hid the HTML5 web players throbber (buffering circle animation) using CSS?

I've managed to hid all other elements of the HTML5 web player using the following CSS:

```
.myClass::-webkit-media-controls-panel {
  display: none;
}

.myClass::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
  display: none;
}

.myClass::-internal-media-controls-download-button {
  display: none;
}
```

Is there one specific to the throbber?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

```
.myClass::-internal-media-controls {
  display: none;
}
```

This accesses all of the media elements relating to the video player tools.